# Need a script to fetch the redis latency values over 20 seconds and store the results in a file

Tags: bash, shell, redis, redis-cli

I need to periodically update a file that will host the **Redis Latency** values at certain time daily.

I am using the command `redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379`. The issue is that this command works only in interactive mode and it cycles through the values. I want to get the latency values over a certain time period and then put the values in my file.

When I execute the following command with the timeout utility, it runs for the specified 20 seconds:

```bash
timeout 20 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
```

However, when I try to capture the output in a variable (to pass it int the file) like this:

```bash
Latency=$(timeout 20 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379)
echo $Latency
```

The command stops immediately after running, rather than running for the intended 20 seconds.

How can I capture the Redis latency output for the full duration of 20 seconds into a variable?

Comment: Try `redis-cli --help`, read quietly, then `redis-cli -i 20 --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 --raw`

Comment: Timeout works with a simple `echo` command.  It's gotta be a redis issue or how you execute the script.

Comment: @konsolebox `redis-cli --latency` don't work same if output is a *`TTY`*, than if *redirected*!

Comment: For storing *real* output of `redis-cli --latency` into a variable, you could try: `bash -c 'sleep 3;ps --ppid $(ps ho ppid $$) ho pid | xargs kill' & Latency="$(stdbuf -o0 script -f /dev/null -c 'redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379')"` then show the content of your variable: `echo ${Latency@Q}` (Note, I've stored only 3 seconds instead of 20! Feel free to change `3` for `20` in my sample;)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Exactly what I'm thinking but only you guys can verify.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Alright, but why are you telling me that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to capture Redis Latency output to a variable or file, by default Redis samples the latency for 1 second.

To customize the duration of the latency test, you can specify the interval between samples using the **-i** option like this

```
Latency=$(/usr/local/bin/redis-cli --latency -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -i 20)
```

You can get also get this information using the help command for redis latency. [Image from Redis help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtdQw.png)

```
redis-cli --latency --help
```